# What is the use of ampulla in Scoliodon?

Tags: zoology

What exactly is the use of Ampulla of Lorenzi in Scolidon?
It posseses eyes for seeing prey, so what is the use of Ampulla?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! What research have you done before asking it here?

Comment: I am just a student of class 12 and this question is very much important for my knowledge.

Comment: very frankly, being a student of class 12 does not give you liberty to ask here questions lacking prior research effort. The question might be important, and interesting as well, but as long as you don't show an attempt to answer it yourself, we are not willing to help you out. You need to, at least, google about it and then tell us what you have found so far, and how that does not help you :)

Comment: Ok ok , thanks for giving me the exact procedure of asking questions. I'll try to work on this topic in google.

Comment: @Abhijit Have you checked [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampullae_of_Lorenzini)? It says quite a lot of stuff, which should probably be enough for a 12th grader (no school is going to make you right a thesis or something on this topic).